# Ajax and Vue cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

i have a vue cli project, and i am trying to make an ajax call in my application, and it is working if i go on the localhost:7999, but i want it to work on the same page as my application, which is on localhost:8080. i have heard of Axios but maybe if there is a way without using Axios, i am hoping that i could find it here.

vue.config.js

```js
global.changement = "Johnny Depp";

var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var userStoredInMemory = "LEBROONNN JAMES";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  res.json(changement);
});

app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  // userStoredInMemory = req.body;
  // userStoredInMemory = "oui";
  res.send('User was already stored from express.');
});

app.listen(7999, function () {
  console.log('server up and running at 8080 port');
});
```

index.html

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
 
<script>
  
    function lebron() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:7999/api/user'
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                localStorage.setItem('name',JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        });
    }

    setInterval(lebron, 1000);

</script>

<noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but it doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
    
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
```

there is not output, no alert is done.

Comment: There's not enough information. It's unknown what's wrong on your side. Under normal circumstances it would likely work as expected. You're the only person who can debug the request. Network tab and console in dev tools is at your disposal. You could use `fail` to catch the error, in case there's one. Axios is widely used because it's suited for this task and jQuery isn't a common dependency in modern apps.

Comment: first of all if they run on diffrent ports you cannt send ajax request from client to server. you will run into cors problem. you can solve it by just install cors package in node and use its middleware. you can also configure in file vue.config.js to run the server through the express using proxy. take a look here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Comment: why document.ready inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use cors in your server.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => cors({
        origin: 'localhost:8080', // your frontend app url
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true
    })(req, res, next)
);
```